# JSON Weather Feed in PHP

Tags: php, json, weather-api, openweathermap

I am trying to display this weather information by pulling it from a JSON feed in PHP. I can't figure out why it is not printing. Here is the code:

```
$url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Albany,usl&APPID=5099c5feb579c7a17b030de0d009282f&units=metric";
$json=file_get_contents($url);
$data=json_decode($json);



echo '<h1>', $data->name, ' (', $data->sys->country, ')</h1>';

// the general information about the weather
echo '<h2>Temperature:</h2>';
echo '<p><strong>Current:</strong> ', $data->main->temp, '&deg; C</p>';
echo '<p><strong>Min:</strong> ', $data->main->temp_min, '&deg; C</p>';
echo '<p><strong>Max:</strong> ', $data->main->temp_max, '&deg; C</p>';

?>
```

My output is something like:

()

Temperature:

Current: ° C

Min: ° C

Max: ° C

Comment: `$data=json_decode($json, false);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the way you parse the output from the API. Check bellow -

```
    $url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Albany,usl&APPID=5099c5feb579c7a17b030de0d009282f&units=metric";
    $json=file_get_contents($url);
    $data=json_decode($json);

    echo '<h1>', $data->city->name, ' (', $data->city->country, ')</h1>';

    // the general information about the weather
    echo '<h2>Temperature:</h2>';
    echo '<p><strong>Current:</strong> ', $data->list[0]->main->temp, '&deg; C</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>Min:</strong> ', $data->list[0]->main->temp_min, '&deg; C</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>Max:</strong> ', $data->list[0]->main->temp_max, '&deg; C</p>';
```

Comment: Works perfect, Thanks!

Comment: How would I access the description? I am having trouble printing other outputs.

Comment: $data->list[0]-> weather[0]-> description

Comment: hallo i have a question. i tried your code and it's work thanks to you but the output is like this '32.34°'. how to make the output like '33°' ??

Answer (score 0):

You have structure wrong. if you want to see how the json is structured just

```
echo '<pre>',print_r($data,1),'</pre>';
```

for you output you want

```
$url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Albany,usl&APPID=5099c5feb579c7a17b030de0d009282f&units=metric";
$json=file_get_contents($url);
$data=json_decode($json);
echo $data->city->name;
```

Comment: I know how to use the print_r function. Also, have already tried your suggestion and get no output. Here is the print_r link you suggested: http://aswanson.net/Weather/weather.php

Comment: You must have something else wrong my friend. I just ran it in http://phpfiddle.org/ and it output ablany with no problem. Also when I go to http://aswanson.net/Weather/weather.php it outputs like normal. Are you simply not seeing the output? Albany (US)

Temperature:

Current: 29.87° C

Min: 27.67° C

Max: 29.87° C

Conditions: clear sky

Wind Conditions: 1.61